# How to order a dictionary within a list by alphabetical order and highest number

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, highest

I have a basic piece of coding which follows:

```
dict1 = [{"Name":"Ron","one":3,"two":6,"three":10}
         ,{"Name":"Mac","one":5,"two":8,"three":0}
         ,{"Name":"DUDE","one":16,"two":9,"three":2}]

print(dict1)
import operator

dict1.sort(key=operator.itemgetter("Name"))

print("\nStudents Alphabetised\n")
for pupil in dict1:
    print ("StudentName",pupil["Name"],pupil["one"],pupil["two"],pupil["three"])
```

I have sorted out it so it will print out people's names in alphabetical order, however, I now need the code working so it would print out the names in alphabetical order, but also so it prints out the highest score only.

Comment: Can you show exactly what your output should look like?

Comment: ' [{'three': 10, 'Name': 'Ron', 'two': 6, 'one': 3}, {'three': 0, 'Name': 'Mac', 'two': 8, 'one': 5}, {'three': 2, 'Name': 'DUDE', 'two': 9, 'one': 16}]

Students Alphabetised

Student Name DUDE 16 9 2
Student Name Mac 5 8 0
Student Name Ron 3 6 10 '

Comment: I mean't, include in queston what your expected output looks like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your scores are stored in three separate keys; use the [`max()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) to pick the highest one:

```
for pupil in dict1:
    highest = max(pupil["one"], pupil["two"], pupil["three"])
    print("StudentName", pupil["Name"], highest)
```

You could make your life easier by storing all the scores in a list, rather than three separate keys:

```
dict1 = [
    {"Name": "Ron", 'scores': [3, 6, 10]},
    {"Name": "Mac", 'scores': [5, 8, 0]},
    {"Name": "DUDE", 'scores': [16, 9, 2]},
]
```

You can then still address individual scores with `pupil['scores'][index]` (where `index` is an integer, pick from 0, 1 or 2), but the highest score is then as simple as `max(pupil['scores'])`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate the help.